# Pasting a pivot table into values, allowing me to edit the numbers, while maintaing the subtotal/grandtotal sum formula

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am not sure if this is possible

I have this table:

[image]https://imgur.com/jqTb0Th

Is it possible for me to paste this table into value, allowing me to edit the numbers for T0 and T1, while still maintaining the subtotal/grandtotal formula?

Something like this

[image]https://imgur.com/eNtyspD

Thank you so much for the help

The imgur is just a quick pivot i made, the actual pivot table have dozens of subtotals for rows/columns

Currently the process is a person pastes the Pivot table into values

- and then manually writes B3+B4 and so on for all the subtotal boxes
- and then we can start work with manual injections of funds

I'm basically expecting

1. Creation of Pivot Table for presentation
2. nothing from the Pivot table format except for the data and subtotal formula

Comment: It might be better to replicate the pivot table with formulas.

Comment: You can't modify the pivot result. You may want to look into =GETPIVOTDATA() or as suggested write formulas to return what you need.